# Organizing a network without an internet connection

Tags: local

Every year some teachers from our schools travel to a far away place where we organize scientific courses and other educational activities for children in the nearby places.

Unfortunately, there is no Internet there and there is no way to find it in the vicinity. So, this year, we thought, that probably we could bring up a kind of a local network and put up a site there (we will still use wi-fi to spread the network over the local buildings), so that students could be able to post their discoveries / blog posts / photos.

My questions are the following:

1. Is it at all possible to install a 'server' or something and run a local netwrok? (we have a few routers / laptops (Windows)
2. Is it possible to run a site with a forum / chat / blog / something on this 'local network'? What way to look? Joomla? Drupal? WordPress?
3. I have next to no experience, so I need an easy to go solution. If possible - free. I know it will require a lot of reading - and I would be glad if someone told me the key words / things I need to look into / up?

Now, what is important is that I am not against reading / self-studying, but I need to be pointed in the direction that will lead me to the desirable solution, not just "how to set up a secure / top-notch" network that will take me years to get the grip of.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just buy/use a modem/router with built-in wireless (you may need an ethernet switch if you need lots of ethernet connected devices). The router will provide DHCP so the devices can communicate with each other/the server.

Your network:

Router/wifi -> switch -> server & ethernet clients.

The server can run, say, WAMP (for a Windows box) and just configure it to listen on 0.0 0.0 (all addresses) so that your users can access the internal website. You can then install whatever you like - WordPress, Joomla, forums, etc. as normal. Just pass the server IP to your users (or create a virtual host so people can go to a URL).

The only cost implications are If you don't have a router and switch and ethernet cables.

A potential issue you may encounter is if lots of people conect simultaneously and the router you use can't cope with the number of connections. Updating your question with max number of people connecting could be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From your experience, if I have about 50-100 people trying to connect, will an ordinary notebook be able to service al the requests? I mean, it will be a 'server', right? And it said that server PC is much more powerful, than ordinary.

Comment: I don't have experience of 50-100 users uploading using a notebook but accessing the webserver to "read" was ok (not great but did the job). I wonder if your router will be able to service that number of simultaneous connections, however. Someone on here may be able to jump in with a potential solution. You may need to invest in additional access points for wifi, for example.

Comment: What is the worst case scenario - if the router / server is not able to support so many connection will it just shut down? Or just people will have to wait till others finish the posting?

Comment: P.s. a "server" in a production environment is powerful because it has a lot of money put into it to provide the performance for the desired demand. Using a laptop doesn't mean it's a server, it's a server because it is running a piece of software that can "serve" requests. If you put too much demand on it out will slow down and have problems, but your traffic should be "ok" (but not great)